# Looping through files, one file processes, then that's it, no error reporting

Tags: php, json, loops, file-get-contents

So I have a problem with a script I'm working on. I have a folder full of JSON files called roster0.json, roster1, etc. etc.

```
$dir = "responses/";
$files = glob($dir . "roster*");
$failed = array();
$failcnt = 0;

if (isset($files)) {
   $data = null;
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) {
        $data = json_decode(utf8_decode(file_get_contents($files[$i])));
        if(isset($data)){
            // Process stuff
```

When I var_dump($files) I get an array with over 100 paths "responses/roster0.json".
When I test $data I get a proper array of data.
However, once the loop goes to the next file, it never loads it, and never processes it.

Here's the crazy part. If I change the start of the for loop, e.g. $i = 20. It will load the 21st file in the directory and parse it and insert it into the db properly!

Ignoring the failcnt stuff at the bottom, here's the current version of the script in it's entirety. http://pastebin.com/yqyKi5Ag

PS - I have full WARNING/ERROR reporting on in PHP and not getting any error messages...HELP! Thanks!

Comment: how are you executing the PHP? if you are executing it in a browser the error will be in the web server error log. If you have SSL logs configured and access the script using SSL the error will be in the corresponding log

Comment: Our server usually drops off an error_log file and there is none.

Comment: have you tried to write something wrong and see if the error appears in the log?

Comment: Didn't get too far down the code but your use of [isset](http://php.net/isset) is technically incorrect because the things you are checking are always set.  Maybe you want `!== null` and `is_array` in some cases.  Also, `json_decode(utf8_decode(file_get_contents($files[$i])));` doesn't throw any exceptions so the try...catch around it will never catch the error.  Read the docs on each of the functions to see what they return when they fail and check for those values.

Comment: A PS - ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); is on.

Comment: Yeah I tried the try / catch to see if it was reading it as null. As I described if I change the start of $i it reads/parses just fine.

Comment: Also a further note, all JSON files are reporting as valid when loaded in a validator.

Comment: Can you post all code in the `for` loop, please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Yhp8Xj05

This is the latest code.

Comment: So I feel like a total moron, but I figured it out. 

When I was writing the insert string the ID was being duplicated and thus was invalid. Switched to auto-inc and tada. It works. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

When I was writing the insert string the ID was being duplicated and thus was invalid. Switched to auto-inc and tada. It works. Thanks for the assistance. –